# My css and js for custom plugin load fine on my default page but when i search some thing from search bar it wont load my plugin js or css

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code where I've by default bound my custom plugin(star rating)  to show up under every post, but when I search this post(sultan) from the search box post it shows up but my plugin go ruff and do not show stars just show

> Please rate: 5 stars 4 stars 3 stars 2 stars 1 star

instead of tje stars.

Although I checked page source my css and js file is loading but dont know y its not working

image with star working on default page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEUKl.png)

image with star not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvSVB.png)

```
function wpa_rating_ad($content) {
global $post;
$thePostID = $post->ID; 
    $star='
    <p>
        <div class="rating">
            <legend>Please rate:</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="star5-'.$thePostID.'"  name="rating" value="5" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                <label  for="star5-'.$thePostID.'" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="4" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                <label  for="star4-'.$thePostID.'" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="3" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                <label  for="star3-'.$thePostID.'" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="2" data-id="'.$thePostID.'" class="rating-star" />
                <label for="star2-'.$thePostID.'" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1-'.$thePostID.'" name="rating" value="1" data-id="'.$thePostID.'"  class="rating-star" />
                <label for="star1-'.$thePostID.'" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
        </div>
    </p> 
    <p>
        <div id="services-name-'.$thePostID.'" class="services-btn">
        </div>
    </p>'
    ;

     return $content.$star;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpa_rating_ad');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check wordpress documentation, url https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion